# How to use non-capturing group in VBA regex?

Tags: regex, vba

With VBA, I'm trying to use regex to capture the filename from a UNC path without the extension--looking at .TIF files only.

So far this is what I have:

```
Function findTIFname(filestr As String) As String

Dim re As RegExp
Dim output As String
Dim matches As MatchCollection

Set re = New RegExp
re.pattern = "[^\\]+(?:[.]tif)$"
Set matches = re.Execute(filestr)
If matches.Count > 0 Then
    output = matches(0).Value
Else
    output = ""
End If
findTIFname = output

End Function
```

But when I run the function as follows:

```
msgbox findTIFname("\\abc\def\ghi\jkl\41e07.tif")
```

I get the following output:

```
41e07.tif
```

I thought that "(?:xxx)" was the regex syntax for a non-capturing group; what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Nice code! I use something very similar, but I use a second paramter for the re.pattern so I can just pass in any paramter rather than hard-code it. Just a tip: VBA will automatically make output = "" when you declare it, so there is no need for that Else statement at the end. And instead of using > 0, you can use <> 0 for better optimization (faster to check for inequality).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The syntax `(?:...)` is a *non-capturing group*. What you need here is a *positive lookahead assertion* which has a `(?=...)` syntax like so:

`re.pattern = "[^\\]+(?=[.]tif$)"`

Note that lookaround assertions have *zero width* and consume no characters.

Comment: This was very helpful to me too - thanks.  Now I am confused what a non-capturing group is even for.  Would you append and briefly explain?

Comment: @Praesagus - No, but even better allow me to steer you to an excellent tuorial on the subject: [Lookaround Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). This comprehensive website tutorial is an excellent reference for all things regex. Enjoy!

Answer (score 5):

Do you really need to do this with **RegEx**?
Access (or better, MS Office) has built-in ways to do this quite easily without RegEx.

You just need to reference the Microsoft Scripting Runtime (which should be included in every MS Office installation, as far as I know).
Then you can use the `FileSystemObject`:

```
Public Function findTIFname(filestr As String) As String

    Dim fso As FileSystemObject
    Set fso = New FileSystemObject

    If fso.GetExtensionName(filestr) = "tif" Then
        findTIFname = fso.GetBaseName(filestr)
    End If

    Set fso = Nothing

End Function
```

Given your example UNC path `\\abc\def\ghi\jkl\41e07.tif`, this will return `41e07`.

Comment: That's cool. I've never used GetBaseName before - this could be helpful in the future. ^^

Comment: I didn't say that FSO is **more** built-in than RegEx. My point is: why use RegEx to get a file name out of a path when there **is** a class that serves exactly that purpose.

Comment: The types in Microsoft Scripting Runtime aren't part of Office, but can be used from any COM-supporting environment, including VBScript, Borland Delphi and .NET languages (though why you wouldn't want to use the .NET `Path` class is beyond me).