# How to get the content of parentheses but not the parentheses themselves

Tags: regex, vba

I have this kind of text `1323-DI-004 (2013-07-16).pdf` and I want to have the date placed in parentheses. I tried with the regex `(\(.*)\)`. It give this `(2013-07-16)`. I want to have the same result but without parenthses.

This is for a VBA code.

Is it possible and how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit: you're using VBA, so**

```
Dim myMatches As MatchCollection
Set myRegExp = New RegExp
myRegExp.Pattern = "\((.*)\)"
Set myMatches = myRegExp.Execute(subjectString)
MsgBox(myMatches(1).Value) 'I think this be your reference? You may need to iterate myMatches to get the right one
```

---

Assuming this is a fully PCRE compliant matching platform (PHP, PERL, etc. -- *not* javascript), use [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to achieve this, matching the `()` on either side without including them in the capture:

```
(?<=\()(.*)(?=\))
```

See it in action: http://regex101.com/r/oI3gD6

If you're using javascript, this won't work, however you can use `\((.*)\)` and retrieve the first capture group, which will be what's inside the `()`.

Comment: This is for VBA and I don't think it's possible to have each groups.

Comment: @Dougui VBA indeed doesn't seem to support lookbehind, but you should be able to use groups (based on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852005/how-to-use-non-capturing-group-in-vba-regex), this line - `matches(0).Value` - presumably you can make that `matches(1).Value` to get the first group).

Comment: The class ``MatchCollection` does not seems to exist. Finally, I did this : `Replace(Replace(ExtractDate(Path), "(", ""), ")", "")`. Uggly solution but it works.